# Server 2016 - Folder access still allowed despite Deny Rule

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2016

I have a problem with a Win 2016 Server.
There is a folder which all Users of an AD-Group can access. Inside there is a folder which not all users are supposed to get access to.

I have the following groups set up in my AD:

- *GroupA* (Global, Security)

  - Includes Users U1-U5
- *GroupB* (Global, Security)

  - Includes just Users U1-U3

Now on to the folders:

- *FolderUpper*

  - GroupA is allowed to: change, read (execute), show content, read, write
- *FolderInner* (lies inside *FolderUpper*)

  - *GroupA* can do the same here obviously
  - *GroupB* is set to Deny (FullAccess)

But users in *GroupB* can still access the folder.
Any idea why this is the case? Those users are in both *GroupA* and *GroupB*. One allows access one denys access and I thought deny > access so I don't understand why the still get access.

when I set the unser to deny idividually the are no longer allowed in but it's a pain to deny every single user so working with a group that is set to deny would be ideal.

regards

Comment: Are you sure the server is aware of those users' group memberships? Were they added just today, after the users already got their Kerberos tickets for the day?

Comment: GroupB was added today, one user in GroupB was also added today. The rest of the users in GroupB already existed for a few years now. I ran a gpupdate /force from an elevated prompt as well but doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I meant _added to the group._ The user's existence doesn't matter; but the user's group memberships are remembered at login time and not re-checked on each access. (And gpupdate has nothing to do with groups at all...)

Answer (score 1):

The users must logoff and logon again from their workstations before the group membership is effective, because group membership is retrieved from the Kerberos token which is acquired while logging in.